# Android-Studio: Gradle doesn't find HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, android-studio

After hours of fighting with android-studio and HoloEverywhere+ActionBarSherlock, I finally managed to set everything up; The holoeverywhere classes are found in android-studio. However, upon "Make" or "Compile" of my project, I am getting the following errors:

```
Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Holo.Theme'.
Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'.
Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Holo.Theme.Light'.
Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'.
```

Now, in my `themes.xml` file, I create some styles that inherit from `Holo.Theme` and `Holo.Theme.Light`. It did work in Eclipse, and since HoloEverywhere seems to be found and is added as a dependency of my project, why does gradle not find these definitions?

The code is, as usual:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light">
...
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item>
...
</style>
```

Thank you for your help!

---

By the way, the styles are found by android-studio, since it doesn't complain in the editor. Only when I make or compile, these errors appear.

---

Another thing, which may help: I tried removing the HoloEverywhere Stuff from the xml, and compile, and gradle also complained about the Java classes. So, it appears as if gradle doesn't find anything of HoloEverywhere. Do I have to add it to the build.gradle or something?

Comment: If you go to project structure, is the module marked as an Android Library? You can expand it from the list and click on the Android icon, and ensure that it is marked correctly. It also should be marked as a requirement on the app's module.

Comment: Yes, all the modules my app depends on are marked as Library. They have the "Android" facet (but not the Android-Gradle facet, since they are not gradle projects). All are marked as a dependency of my app, otherwise, android-studio wouldn't recognize them in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the library resource path to your project's build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res','(library-res-path)']
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of "library-res-path".

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/images/tools/project-layout.png) is a gradle project structure. If you copy your library folder into MyApplication, 'library-res-path' will be :MyLibrary/(path-to-res-folder).

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression that I wouldn't need to copy the library folder into my project folder. If I do that, this gets resolved automatically.

Comment: This solved my problem. gradle was breaking at the :processDebugResources step and add the res.srcDirs fixed it. Thanks

Comment: This generates the error: Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project '(projectname)'.
> Could not find method sourceSets() for arguments [build_74kod5rkhk6e5e8krkkaks7tds$_run_closure1@706c08b2] on root project '(projectname)'.

Comment: The consumer module (the main app) is being evaluated before the producer (the library); therefore, '(library-res-path)' is not known yet. There are two workarounds for this: add the line `evaluationDependsOn(':library')` ( `:library` should be written the same way it is defined in the settings.gradle file) OR add `evaluationDependsOnChildren()`; one of these lines (or multiple calls to `evaluationDependsOn(library)` should be added BEFORE `apply-plugin:` in the build.gradle file of the main module.